# Converting regex for use in php preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I've been hitting a brick wall with trying to use the following regex in PHP.

```
<li.*?class="(.*?gchoice.*?)">((.|\n)*?)<\/li>
```

This works fine in the following test selecting only the nested list item when i try it in a jquery based tester

```
 <li class="gfield gfield_contains_required" id="field_1_17">
<label class="gfield_label">Categories<span class="gfield_required"> (Required) </span>        </label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<ul id="input_1_17" class="gfield_checkbox">
<li class="gchoice_17_1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice_17_1" value="First Choice" name="input_17.1">
    <label id="label_17_1" for="choice_17_1">First Choice</label>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
```

However in PHP it just doesn't want to work no matter how I try to escape the characters and no matter the delimiter I try and use. From what I know I should only need a / or # at the stand and end, however when that did not work I tried escaping the brackets as well and yet it still didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regex to parse HTML?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use regex.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_source);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$target = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class,'gchoice')]");
foreach($target as $node) {
    var_dump($node); // do something
}
```

Comment: So much better. :) @ChrisMorris I removed my answer, but for your reference look up the `(?s)` modifier.

Comment: I can't do this as I need the regex to pick up the rest of the class name, the name is dynamic so I only know the first part, Unless there is a way with the DOM method to wildcard the class name.

Comment: @ChrisMorris The answer uses the Contains function.  So it looks for li nodes that has a class attribute that includes the substring gchoice.  What further need for wildcards do you need?  Once you have the node extracting the complete class attribute should be straight forward.

Comment: Sorry I've not used DOM I'm struggling to see how I could use this as I'm also trying to replace that node with a preg_replace later in my code.

Comment: @ChrisMorris Keep using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) functions, as they will ensure that your result is valid no matter what.